# Executing a python script within sql server

Tags: python, sql-server

Experts,

Just curious to know. is there any way of executing the python scripts within any sql server?

if so please provide me with some reference link

Comment: AFAIK with MS SQL server no, with postgreSQL yes.

Comment: Useful link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/run-python-using-t-sql

Comment: some useful links that might help you!
[https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5037/execute-python-scripts-with-management-studio-to-securely-import-data-into-sql-server/]
[https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5036/installing-python-and-running-python-scripts-from-sql-server-ssms/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute python script in sql server reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464928/run-python-script-from-mssql)

And for more detail information read this [doc](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-python-in-sql-server-2017-to-obtain-advanced-data-analytics/)

I hope this helps you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm far from an expert but was recently looking this, so here's a very simple T-SQL script with embedded Python if it helps anyone (Note: assumes you have [Machine Learning Services with Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/sql-server-python-services) all set up on SQL Server).

```
-- Stored proc which runs embedded Machine Learning Services scripts
EXEC sp_execute_external_script

-- The SQL query to be input to the Python script
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT TOP(100) [CustomerID], [JobNumber] 
                  FROM [dbo].[Heading] ORDER BY DateDelivery DESC',

-- Variable name for the input SQL data ('InputDataSet' is the default if none)
@input_data_1_name = N'InputDataSet',

-- The language of the script
@language = N'Python',

-- Python script itself - Just imports Pandas and creates a new DataFrame with only one of the two input columns
@script = N'
import pandas as pd
OutputDataSet = pd.DataFrame(InputDataSet["CustomerID"])
'

-- Declaring SQL columns for the output (a Pandas DataFrame)
WITH RESULT SETS (
    ("CustomerID" INT NULL)
)
```