# Can we connect Cosmos DB to SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, azure-cosmosdb

I have to use Azure Cosmos DB in SSRS reports. I have used ODBC connector. I am able to fetch data using simple select query. But not able call stored procedure or function in SSRS reports. Is it possible to call Cosmos DB stored procedure in SSRS like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cosmos DB is not a relational database, and its stored procedures are not the same thing as a SQL Server stored procedure (and there is no SQL in a Cosmos DB stored procedure; only JavaScript, executing against the documents within a specific partition).

You cannot call a Cosmos DB stored procedure from SSRS. You can only invoke a Cosmos DB stored proc via SDK (or REST API) call.

Comment: Can we create conditional statements in COSMOS db like case, if conditions in sql?

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos DB not being a relational database and its procedures being written in Javascript are irrelevant factoids in the context of the question.

There are ways you could directly and indirectly query data in Cosmos via a stored procedure in SQL Server which in turn could be used as the datasource for SSRS reports.

1) Write a Python script that connects to Cosmos DB, queries the data you're looking for into JSON documents, and writes these to a file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-python-samples.

If this query in Cosmos requires scanning documents in multiple partitions you can enable cross partition queries. "To run a query across partitions, set EnableCrossPartitionQuery to true (or x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition in the REST API)"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-query-container

2) Create a stored procedure in SQL Server. Use xp_cmdshell in the SQL Server stored procedure to execute the Python script in step 1. Or you can create an agent job in SQL Server with a powershell step -- and the stored procedure can execute this job.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

[Run Python Script from MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464928/run-python-script-from-mssql)

Use BULK INSERT in the procedure to insert the JSON data in the file into a table in SQL Server -- then use the T-SQL OPENJSON function to parse the JSON into columnar form.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

3) Add the stored procedure as the datasource for an SSRS report.

If you're using the MongoAPI you could also directly query Cosmos using Polybase in SQL Server 2019.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-mongodb?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect Cosmos DB to SQL using Cosmos DB ODBC Connector.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/odbc-driver#connect

2. Create a stored procedure to call Cosmos object using OPENQUERY command like below.

```
Select * FROM OPENQUERY( select * from [CosmosDB].[Table] )
```

https://www.sqlshack.com/link-an-azure-cosmos-db-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/

3. Once having the stored procedure, it should be easy to use it in SSRS.