# Does SQL server 2012 support to call external python script?

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2012, external-script

Does SQL server 2012 support to call external python script ?

Comment: I believe you can use SQLCMD to call programs from SQL Server. However, reading data from Python scripts into SQL Server, I don't think it's possible in SQL Server 2012 (if you intend to do that).

Comment: That linked question, above, is really a duplicate of [Run Python Script from MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464928/run-python-script-from-mssql); as the answer just links to a different question; and an off site resource (without quoting); it's actually a really low quality answer imo.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2012 does not support executing external Python Scripts. As per the documentation for [sp_execute_external_script (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Executes a script provided as an input argument to the procedure.
>   Script runs in the extensibility framework. Script must be written in
>   a supported and registered language, on a database engine having at
>   least one extension: R, Python, or Java (in SQL Server 2019 preview
>   only).

This then later goes on to state the following in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) Section:

> Use sp_execute_external_script to execute scripts written in a
>   supported language. Currently, supported languages are R for SQL
>   Server 2016 R Services, and Python and R for SQL Server 2017 Machine
>   Learning Services.

You can also confirm the supported languages by version by looking at the [Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) section, specifically `@Language`:

> **@language** = *N'language'*
>  Indicates the script language. *language* is **sysname**. Depending on your version of SQL Server, valid
>   values are R (SQL Server 2016 and later), Python (SQL Server 2017 and
>   later), and Java (SQL Server 2019 preview).

As you can see, you need at least 2017 to use `sp_execute_external_script` to execute a Python Script using the built in tools, and the earliest that can execute external Scripts is 2016 (and only R then).

This does not mean you couldn't do it a different way; such as using `xp_cmdshell` or using an SSIS package to call them, but we don't have any details on your end goal to give more information than this.

Comment: Wow, the language in the document is bad a times; some of it is certainly written in what I would call "broken" English.

Answer (score -1):

I think that feature was introduced in SQL Server 2016, check this link out for more info
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5036/installing-python-and-running-python-scripts-from-sql-server-ssms/