# How to execute external python script file (which is hosted on remote desktop) from SQL Server MS

Tags: python, sql-server

How can I execute python project, which is hosted on remote desktop from my local SQL server management studio (ideally from stored procedure). I tried to look [Run Python Script from MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464928/run-python-script-from-mssql) into this but I am not aware of how to use it.

The python script ideally has some print statement, ideally I should able to read those print statements from SQL server too

Comment: If the script is stored elsewhere, you could use something like `OPENROWSET` to put the contents of the file in a variable, and then execute the Python using `sys.sp_execute_external_script`.

Comment: The main file internally uses multiple other python files, hence putting contents in variable can't be used

Comment: *"How can I execute python script file"* emphasis on *singular* file... if you want to run a python file that is part of a project, that is very different. This doesn't sound like this is a task for SQL Server any more. `sys.sp_execute_external_script` can't call files.

Comment: Any idea if we can do this by using sql jobs?